# Read Mincraft texture pack OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

I am trying to create a Mincraft game using OpenGL, and I was wondering how could I use the official texture pack for my project.

But unlike other sources (obj files for example) I couldn’t find a way to get the data about the model (meshes, vertices, Indic’s, texture cords, etc) all I could find was the texture itself.

So first of all I would like to know if such a thing is even possible, and if yes how.

Comment: never played minecraft but I think there are no mesh files in it so no meshes,texcoords,etc... Instead there should be some Voxel map (3D texture probably compressed or sparse matrix) and the mesh is generated by code on the run. See also this [(archive for low rep users) How to best write a voxel engine in C with performance in mind](https://web.archive.org/web/20180618064202/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48090782/how-to-best-write-a-voxel-engine-in-c-with-performance-in-mind/48092685#48092685) for alternative

Comment: I was talking about the modules like the character's and the animals. This is the link to the files (https://texture-packs.com/resourcepack/default-pack/amp/)

Comment: from what I see there are no textcoords only frames so either you use whole resolution (just corner points) or divide one axis to frames I see no rule to which one in the description file however looks like buttons are in x and blocks in y ? as you map the texture to face of QUAD you really do not need anything else ...